# How can I fill the face just between the vertices and not the inner circle?

Tags: modeling

[image]

So, as the title suggests, I want to fill JUST inbetween the inner and outer circles, but whenever I fill them in, it'll fill in that inner circle, something I don't want, I've tried different selections of vertices and edges, but it still fills everything in. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3):

What you want is "Bridge Edge Loops". Select the two "rings" you want to connect, right-click, and select it. Do this for both sides. See below:

[image: BridgeEdges]